# Check that Instant now happens during the java.time.Period / Duration

Tags: java-8, java.time.instant

My intent is to set a condition to true only during a period.

The `java.time.*` API looked what I need.

```
import java.time.Period
import java.time.LocalTime
import java.time.Instant
import java.time.Duration

// java.time.Period
LocalTime start = LocalTime.of(1, 20, 25, 1024);
LocalTime end = LocalTime.of(3, 22, 27, 1544);
Period period = Period.between(startDate, endDate);

// java.time.duration
Instant start = Instant.parse("2017-10-03T10:15:30.00Z")
Instant end = Instant.parse("2019-10-03T10:16:30.00Z")
Duration duration = Duration.between(start, end)

Instant now = Instant.now();
```

How to check that `now` is happening during the defined Period / Duration ?

I see no direct API.

Edit : 
I found a way with `java.time.Instant`

```
// now, start and end are defined above
// if now is between start and end 
if (now.isAfter(start) && now.isBefore(end)){
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are mistaken about what `Period` and `Duration` are.

They are *distances* (subtract beginning from ending). `Period` between 01/03/2018 and 01/10/2018 is exactly the same as in between 05/04/1990 and 05/11/1990, same thing for `Duration`. So that means nothing to ask something like "*is 3rd january, 2018* in *3 months*?"

Answer (score 2):

**First: a simple solution:**

```
LocalTime start = LocalTime.of(1, 20, 25, 1024);
LocalTime end = LocalTime.of(3, 22, 27, 1544);
LocalTime now = LocalTime.now()

boolean nowIsInTimeWindow = !(now.isBefore(start) || now.isAfter(end));
```

The same pattern works with LocalDate and LocalDateTime.

**Second: additional thoughts on your original post:**

1. `now` will *never* happen "during" `period` or `duration`. Both are just amounts of time, like "two days" or "five minutes". They don't contain information about start or end.
2. I'd suggest to not mix `Instant` and `LocalDate` but to use `LocalTime` instead of `Instant`. Thus you're consistent with regard to timezone: The `Local...` types are by definition timezone agnostic.

Comment: you took the solution I gave in my "edit" :)

It looks strange that `Period/Duration` don't have an API to check that an `Instant` is in their time window

Comment: You were just too quick finding out while I still wrote an anser. ;-)
Still: refrain from mixing LocalTime and Instant easily!

LocalTime.now() may differ depending on your location on earth.
Instant.now() should be the same in all places.

Doesn't look strange to me. Both classes are NOT about time windows, but only measuring time passing. Imagine asking: "When did five hours and six minutes start?" That does not make sense.